# Python Bokeh 2.0.1 - a JS callback for UndoTool?

Tags: python, bokeh

I've recently started working with Bokeh 2.0.1 on Anaconda. My overarching goal is to visualize some datasets as self-contained html files, with Bokeh menu tools.

In addition to existing tools, I've added a functionality where DoubleTap places a label on the plot at the tap's coordinates. It works as planned, however, I want this operation to be undoable via the standard Bokeh UndoTool. I tried adding a CustomJS callback to the UndoTool instance of the figure in question. However, I can't get this to work - when I click on the Undo button in the figure, the added label doesn't disappear. Apparently, the "undoing" callback doesn't get triggered.

I know that the "undoing" callback is not a problem, because I've also bound it to a button and it works as planned.

The concept code is:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.events import MenuItemClick, ButtonClick
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Button
from bokeh.events import DoubleTap

add_label = CustomJS(--something--)
remove_label = CustomJS(--something else--)

f_h = figure(tools='undo')
f_h.js_on_event(DoubleTap, add_label) # Works as planned - adds a label on a double tap

loc_button = Button()
loc_button.js_on_event(ButtonClick, remove_label) # Also works as planned - removes the last added label

f_h.tools[0].js_on_event(MenuItemClick, remove_label) # Doesn't work - aside from the standard scaling undo behavior nothing happens
```

Thanks in advance,

P.V.

Comment: Thanks, Eugene, for the working example. The reseting event indeed gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `reset` event:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure(tools='reset')
p.circle(x=0, y=0)

p.js_on_event('reset', CustomJS(code="console.log('Resetting!')"))

show(p)
```